# What is PowerShell command output default location?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017

Following this [official Azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). When I run the following PowerShell command (mentioned in `Create a project ZIP file` section of the tutorial), it runs successfully but I don't know where the zip file created by the command is located.

```
Compress-Archive -Path * -DestinationPath myAppFiles.zip
```

I don't see the file in following location either: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`. What is the default output location for PS command?

Comment: Using the search functionality in Windows Explorer doesn't locate the file for you? Or typing `dir` at the PS prompt to see what the current directory is?

Comment: @KenWhite Using your suggestion of running `dir` I was able to find the file (thank you). But I was running the command at the default location of PS instead of location of current directory of the project (that was instructed by the tutorial). So, the zip file I found was of no use (as you can imagine) since it was zipping the files from PS folder itself. But I learnt something from your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default output location in this case is your current working directory. Running that cmdlet as posted will copy everything in the current directory into `$CurrentDirectory\myAppfiles.zip`

Note that as you're not specifying the actual path,  you'll want to `Set-Location` to the actual location of the items you're trying to compress. When you do that, the `.zip` file will end up in that directory.

Comment: To add on, there are a number of ways to determine your current location, but the easiest would either be the `Get-Location` command or the `$pwd` automatic variable.

Comment: @Chakani Your suggestion worked (thank you) and helped me pay attention to the first sentence of `Create a project ZIP file` section of the tutorial: `Make sure you're still in the root directory of the sample project.`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Your comment helped me first set the proper location for the PS command to run. I was running the command in the default location of PS. Thank you.